# Symfony2 form - edit saved data

Tags: symfony-2.1

I'm looking for guidance how to have form prefilled with data taken from existing object. I guess it should be working with method setData, I was expecting something simple like
`$form->setData($existingObject)` but no success.

*For better explanation let's have a simple example.*
I have form where user inputs his personal data. Form is created in controller by calling form.factory,

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new personType());
```

I have form class "personType" and this form class has defined data_class object called "person". User submits form, data are saved in object person and this object is saved in session. I need to have option reopen the form and fill in data saved in object stored in session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you need to create/find your object then pass it to your createForm

> $task = new Task();
>   $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
>   $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));
>
> $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes

In your exemple, try

> $person = ...;
>    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new personType(), $person);

Comment: Thanks for hint, I changed call to $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new personType(),$person); that is fine, now I see variable $options['data'] contains my object in function buildForm but I'm missing last step I guess, I tried to call $builder->setData($options['data']); but nothing changed. If I dump variable $form in controller I see it already contains values taken from object but form fields are still empty. Fields are shown in twig like this {{ form_widget(form.name) }} I don't expect any problem with that.

Comment: OK, I solved the problem. Tib was right and his code solves the problem but I didn't have in my class getter, only magic method __get so unfortunately there was no error and no data as well.